# JAXB query with respect to including Collection during Unmarshalling Process

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

**I am Using JAXB , and this is my XML  Request and the below is the Biding class**

```
<request user="123" Katha="456" />


@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Postdata {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String user;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String Katha;

    // Getters and Setters 

}
```

The above works fine .

Right now we have change in the Request XML which will be in

```
<request user="123" Katha="456"> 
    <Specifier name = "One"/>
    <Specifier name = "Two" />
    <Specifier name = "Three" />
</request>
```

SO please tell me during Unmarshalling process is it possible to include the Specifier as a collection into my Jaxb class ??

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Postdata {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String user;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String Katha;

    // Getters and Setters 



@XmlElemet
    private List<Specifier>
```

Can i do the above way ??

Please let me know ??

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map your use case as follows:

**Postdata**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Postdata {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String user;

    @XmlAttribute(name="Katha")
    private String Katha;

    @XmlElement(name="Specifier")
    private List<Specifier> specifiers;

    // Getters and Setters 

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: Thanks a lot , i have one question , do i need to make a java class Specifier and mention all those attributes of it ??

Comment: @PreethiJain - Yes, you need a class called `Specifier` with to properties `name` and `value` that are annotated with `@XmlAttribute`.